# Select Min value from different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this 3 tables:

Table_Group
/*************************************************/
**GROUP_ID** | **Value_1** | **Value_2** | **Value_3** | 
Group_1      |
a             |
b             |
c            |
Group_2      |
d             |
e             |
f             |

Table_series
/*************************************************/
**SERIE_ID** | **L**    | **W**    | **H**    | 
Serie_1     |
1.5 |
2.0   |
2.2 |
Serie_2     |
1.8 |
3.0   |
3.5 |
Serie_3     |
1.1 |
2.5   |
3.7 |
Serie_4     |
1.3 |
4.5   |
3.7 |

Table_GroupSeries
/*************************************************/
**GROUP_ID** |**SERIE_ID**
Group_1      |Series_1
Group_1      |Series_2
Group_1      |Series_3
Group_2      |Series_4

And I would like to get this table:

**GROUP_ID** |**L_min**|**W_min**|**H_min**
Group_1      |1.1     |2.0         |2.2
Group_2      |1.3     |3.7         |4.5

This means, that I'm trying to get the minimum value of L,W and H for each Group.

How could I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything or would you like us to do it for you?

Comment: Simply by using MIN on each column and a group by GROUP_ID.

Comment: @dfundako I was trying with INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN, but finally the only result that I got it was wrong (3 rows with GROUP 1 and wrong values from L,W,H (they were different in each row)). If it helps, I can copy what I tried, but I thought that it was irrelevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT t1.GROUP_ID, MIN(L) AS L_min, MIN(W) AS W_min, MIN(H) AS H_min
FROM Table_Group AS t1
JOIN Table_GroupSeries AS t2 ON t1.GROUP_ID = t2.GROUP_ID
JOIN Table_series AS t3 ON t2.SERIE_ID = t3.SERIE_ID
GROUP BY t1.GROUP_ID
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I have some problems with JOINs, INNER JOINs and LEFT JOINs. Thanks again